# Select rows where item is only in certain categories

Tags: mysql

So I have a somewhat complicated mysql query question.  I have 3 tables.  One is a table of items.  One is a table of categories.  And one is a linking table that just has 2 fields, itemID and categoryID.  It is a many to many relationship, so one item can be in multiple categories and each category can have multiple items.  Now two of the fields in the category table are isactive and ismain.  They are just bools of 1 or 0.  I want to grab all items that only belong to categories where at either isactive=0 or ismain=0 or both.

I took some time and set up a sql fiddle for someone to play around with.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b03842/2

Answer (score 0):

Solution using subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.* FROM cart_item i 
  JOIN cart_item_category ic ON i.itemref = ic.itemref 
  WHERE ic.catid IN ( 
    SELECT id FROM cart_category WHERE active = 0 OR ismain = 0 
  )
```

Comment: but you can change those conditions to active <> 1 OR ismain <> 1, because you are accepting NULL values for those columns.

Comment: This is closer.  But it is still returning items that belong in both valid and invalid categories.

Comment: do you have to add a `AND NOT IN (SELECT id FROM cart_category WHERE active = 1 AND ismain = 1)`?  something like that?

Comment: sorry, sqlfiddle isn't working for me at the moment so i could not test it. I can try again later.

Comment: @dmikester1, and can test now.. This result isn't correct? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b03842/32/0